# Why could initial iota not create diphthongs?

Tags: phonology, diphthong, linguistics, homeric-greek

In all the textbooks I have seen, the list of Ancient Greek diphthongs are more or less the following:

- αι: /ai̯/

  - ᾳ: /aːi̯/
- αυ: /au̯/

  - ᾱυ /aːu̯/
- ει: /ei̯/ > /eː/

  - ῃ: /ɛːi̯/
- ευ: /eu̯/

  - ηυ: /ɛːu̯/
- οι: /oi̯/

  - ῳ: /ɔːi̯/
- ου: /ou̯/ > /uː/

  - ωυ: /ɔːu̯/
- υι: /yi̯/ > /yː/

(IPA from [*Wikipedia*: ‘Ancient Greek Phonology’: ‘Diphthongs’](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greek_phonology#Diphthongs). List from the same article and compared with Clyde Pharr / John Wright: *Homeric Greek : A Book for Beginners*. In Hansen and Quinn’s *Greek : An Intensive Course*, they specifically state (p. 4) that what Pharr/Wright list as improper diphthongs (long vowel plus short vowel, pronounced as diphthongs in Homeric time (§ 506)) are pronounced as monophthongs by the time of Ancient Greek.*)

From this list I notice that ι cannot be initial in a diphthong. Pharr/Wright notes that ι, υ and ϝ are semi-vowels. Latin, though, included diphthongs with both initial /i/ and /u/, such as Iᴠ́ʟɪᴠs [ˈi̯uːlʲiʊs̠] and ᴠɪ́ɴᴠᴍ [ˈu̯iːnʊ̃ˑ]. (The prior even includes *i* for both the diphthong and the syllabic pure vowel.)

Why then is it that initial /i-/ cannot create a diphthong in Ancient Greek? Did it at some point exist and get monophthongised? I am sorry that I cannot provide any more background for my question, but my knowledge of Greek is horribly poor.

* I understand that Ancient Greek is considered the time period following Homeric Greek; if this is incorrect, I will be very happy to be educated on the matter.

Comment: I think most authorities state that some long diphthongs were viable during most of Ancient/Classical Greek.  According to Sydney Allen, the changes to monophthongs started at least by the 4th century BC (with ῃ) but were not complete until the 2nd century BC during Koine times.  Τhe change can be seen in the different treatment in Latin borrowings of Greek words including ᾠδή.  Early borrowings (*tragoedia* and *comoedia*) show the diphthong.  Later borrowings (*rhapsodia* and *melodia*) do not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Latin had a phonemic `/j/` and `/w/` separate from the vowels `/i/` and `/u/`, hence contrasts like *Julius* vs *Iulus*. The short answer is that "Ancient" Greek—as in Classical Attic—simply didn't. Therefore initial iota is always `/i/`, never `/j/`: Ἰάνθη has a sequence of two vowels like *Iulus*, not a consonant and a vowel like *Julius*.

At one point, the ancestor of Classical Attic *did* have these sounds. `/w/` survived quite a long time in some dialects (though not Attic), to the point that it has a well-recognized letter to represent it: ϝ. And indeed, scansion suggests that Homer (or more precisely one of the people involved in composing and redacting the Homeric epics) pronounced it in words like ϝέπος `/wépos/`, later ἔπος. `/j/` didn't survive to the alphabetic stage, but we see it attested in Mycenaean: Linear B *jo-qi* `/jókkʷi/` for Classical ὅτι. But Attic lost both of these sounds fairly early, and thus has no initial semivowels.

But what about the diphthongs like αι and αυ, you ask? Well, phonologically, they seem to have been treated as single segments rather than sequences of two segments. The second half of αι wasn't affected by the loss of `/j/`, for example, and the second half of αυ wasn't affected by the loss of `/w/`—or, for that matter, by the shift of `/u/` to `/y/`. It seems best to analyze these diphthongs as single atomic units rather than sequences of two vowels, or of a vowel and a semivowel.

Comment: Your point on analyzing diphthongs argues circularly from improperly describing the phenomenon to im-ly generalising the definition and back to the underlying phonology. The data indicateds a loss of semivowels only when in the onset of a syllable, and a fronting of /u/ only when it was syllabic. As soon as we realise we're dealing with a conditioned sound change, there's no necessity to postulate an ontological difference just like loss of final vowels doesn't warrant postulating that they were segmentally different from other vowels. *αυ* is now VC /av/, and /i~j/ was cond. lost in /V:i/

Comment: This comment does appear to have a very strong answer within it, though in the obviously condensed form of a comment, it is—let us agree—quite compact. May I suggest you elaborate on this and provide us with another answer? The more the merrier, after all!

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian Sure, you can analyze it as a conditioned change rather than an actual segmental difference. But then how do you deal with αϋ αϊ etc? There needs to be some difference between αι and αϊ on the segmental level—so you need a difference between /ai/ and /aj/ either way. And at that point I don't see a major difference between analyzing /aj/ as a single unit and analyzing /j/ as a special phoneme that can only ever appear after /a/, /o/, and /y/.

Comment: Nevertheless you affirmed that difference in your answer and that difference (the nature and definition of diphthongs) interests me personally; which is why I decided to remark on your reasoning, that I dont think it stands. /j/ does appear after /e/ in ειV - ostensibly the ambisyllabic /j/ ensured it didn't shift to /i:/ at least until the 1st century AD. αϋ αϊ don't fall under the "syllable initial semivowel deletion" b/c they don't contain semivowels which don't start any syllables. There are two syllabic elements which don't disappear in Greek.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian If you analyze αυ as /av/ (short vowel + consonant), how do you account for the fact that it can be circumflexed?

Comment: (Though one might perhaps make an argument for /j/ in the case of (most) final -αι -οι, as that would make sense of the fact that these count as short syllables for accent purposes.)

Comment: @TKR αυ is /av/ in MoGr, naturally, but anyway: Lithuanian has the so-called 'semi-diphthongs' which only differ from regular ones in that they end in a resonant /n, m, l, r/ (and like in the regular ones, they occur as falling **or rising!**). Slovak has long and short syllabic /l/ and /r/. And English diphthongs are commonly analysed and transcribed as VC sequences /aw/, /uw/, /ey/. Resonants and semivowels therefore form a class called sonorants which share a number of properties with vowels, including the ability to bear accent and tone, then called 'moraic sonorants'.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian It's true that you can describe the facts by saying that Greek has consonants /w j/ that have a very limited distribution and differ from all other consonants in that they can bear tone. But I'm curious why you prefer that to the simpler conventional analysis of these sequences as diphthongs.

Comment: @TKR The question is precisely one level deeper - it's about what a diphthong is, and what relation vowel-semivowel/sonorant sequences bear to diphthongs. The impression from my reading so far is that in most cases it makes sense to talk about diphthongs on the phonetic level, but I'm doubtful that this translates to the segmental (phonemic) level since two-segment descriptions work just as well - and this is also true here. Therefore I think it's the latter that's the simpler, more economical analysis of AGr; Draconis has explicitly gone for the "atomic" analysis, I think on poor evidence

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135348/discussion-between-tkr-and-unbrutal-russian).

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian It appears that Slovak /l/ and /r/ can be treated as vowels, as they are the only ‘consonants’ that can take the vowel lengthening accent.

Comment: @CannedMan That's right, they're like vowels in being able to form the main part of a syllable (the nucleus), but they're still produced in the same way as your typical /l/ and /r/ by occluding the airstream. Phonetically they have a light schwa before or after them. English and German has these as well by the way, as well as the syllabic /n/ and /m/, but only when unstressed, unlike the Slovak liquids.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian AmEng does have stressed syllabic /r/, as in *bird*.

Comment: @TKR You mean it can be analysed in this way :-) But it doesn't have to, and to my understanding its more common analysis is as a rhotic vowel, an r-coloured schwa.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian Fair enough, but presumably that analysis would extend to the unstressed instances too.

Comment: @TKR Personally I think it should be analysed in the same way as the traditional diphthongs - unlike the actual schwa these are clearly bimoraic, so "rhotic diphthongs" if you will. But again, that is a phonetic description - phonemically I don't see a reason to treat that /r/ differently from the onset of *rut,* parallel to how the semivowel in /aw/ is the same segment as in *wacky.*